# Lookup based on result from another lookup

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

I have a table that returns MID based on a concat of id and csid that are in my list. This works as it should.

Can I use the mid to do a lookup on another data extension to return an address? If so, how do i do it?

**Table 1**

| idcsid | mid |
| --- | --- |
| 142 | 1001 |
| 242 | 1002 |
| 345 | 1003 |
| 485 | 1004 |
| 5245 | 1005 |
| 1245 | 1006 |

**script**

```ampscript
%%[ 

Var @id, @csid, @aidcsid, @idcsid,@mid, @row, @rows,@rowcount

Set @id = AttributeValue("id") 
Set @csid = AttributeValue("csid") 
Set @aidcsid = Concat(@id,@csid) 
Set @rows = LookupRows("mid", "idcsid", @aidcsid) 
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows) 


if @rowCount > 0 then set @row = row(@rows,1) 

set @decid = field(@row,"mid") 

 ]%%
```

That works as it should.

I want to have another Data Extension that I can lookup based on mid. Is this possible?

> mid = the derived value based on the previous lookup
> csid = attribute value
> lang = attribute value
> addy = The field I need to return,

So the lookup will be on a concat of mid, csid, lang and then it returns addy.

**Table 2**

| mid | csid | lang | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 42 | en | address in english |
| 1001 | 42 | pt | address in portuguese |
| 1001 | 42 | it | address in italian |
| 1001 | 94 | en | address in english |
| 1001 | 94 | pt | address in portuguese |
| 1001 | 94 | it | address in italian |

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do a lookup or lookuprows using the 3 values as the conditions. I used a simple 'lookup' instead of a lookuprows as you only needed a single value and it looks like its a 1:1 match, so should not need to have consideration of multiple row returns. I also changed your current lookuprows to lookup.

```ampscript
%%[ 

Set @lang = AttributeValue("lang")
Set @id = AttributeValue("id") 
Set @csid = AttributeValue("csid") 
Set @aidcsid = Concat(@id,@csid) 
Set @decid = Lookup("Table1", "mid", "idcsid", @aidcsid) 

IF NOT EMPTY(@decid) THEN
  set @address = Lookup("Table2","address","mid",@decid,"csid",@csid,"lang",@lang)
ENDIF

 ]%%
```

I added in the setting of `@lang` and used `Table1` and `Table2` as the DE names. Other than adjusting those to the correct context, the above should work for your needs.

Comment: will give it a try.

It's lookup rows because I do have other fields that I return from the first table, but didn't add it to the example.

Comment: For sure - can shift to lookuprows or lookuporderedrows as needed.

Comment: busy adjusting. will ask again if I run into issues.

Do I need a loop for this or will it find the row and retrieve the values without it? 

Table 1 and Table 2 DE are around 5K rows and sending to about 30K of recipients